# Beginner Help: PHP MySQL (PDO) Function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to learn PHP and setup a user access based website. I finally found a template that is mostly simple to use and implement. However after hours of struggling to modify the template I have to kindly ask for assistance.

The following code works great and I have modified the original template to be able to login using the email address as username and the stored password from the database. The original template were based on a username login instead of using the email address. What I am trying to achieve now is to somehow also include the field "username" from the same database and table and store it as a $username parameter to use elsewhere on the site, for example with "echo". I would like to still use the field but for the name of the registered member, rather than a username for login.

I'm sure there is an easy way but whatever I change I keep getting error messages and I simply seem to not understand the syntax just yet.

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{
private $_db;
function __construct($db){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_db = $db;
}
private function get_user_hash($email){ 
    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE email = :email AND active="Yes"');
        $stmt->execute(array('email' => $email));
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['password'];

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}

public function login($email,$password){
    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($email);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        return true;
    }   
}

public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}
public function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
        return true;
        }       
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I'd like to ask a few things. 1. In the future could you not put things like:"Beginner help" in the title? 2. Can you be specific about the errors you're getting when you're saying stuff like:*I keep getting error messages*? Thank you.

Comment: I apologize for this and will make sure to keep this in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to extend your code slightly.

at the moment your query is only bringing out 1 field, the password.

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = :email AND active="Yes"
```

this will then return the whole row, not just one field.

you can then extract the username and put it in a session variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
```

which you can then use throughout the rest of the site.  Make sure you have `session_start();` at the beginning of all files that youd like to access the session vars.  If you want to use other fields, then just change the parameter to `'firstName'`, or `'fullName'` or whatever the fields are called.

as a bit extra, you could also extend your query to allow the user to log in with their email OR their username by adding this.

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE (email = :email OR username = :email) AND active="Yes"
```

if you were going to do that, Id suggest changing the `:email` holder to something more sensible like `:user` so that it makes more sense to read the code.

**edit**

your'e going to need to get your `get_user_hash()` function to return back `$row` in its entirety, and then add your session var from there.  Its a bit back to front as this probably isn't the best login script I've ever seen.

in `get_user_hash()`, change

```
 return $row['password'];
```

to

```
  return $row;
```

and then in function login,

```
public function login($email,$password){
    $row = $this->get_user_hash($email);
    $hashed = $row['password'];

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

really, `$hashed` is nothing more than the users password which `password_verify()` uses to compare the encrypted password in the db.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

However I cannot seem to get it to work and I think the problem is that I do not know where to put the: $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

Comment: updated answer. give that a go. Please accept the answer if its useful to you. and good luck.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much for your help and the quick response. I hope someday I will be able to extend a helping hand in this field as well.